# Android: Create diamond button with icon and text inside

Tags: android

I would please like to know how to create a diamond shaped button with an icon and text inside. Like in the image below. If i rotate the button then the image and icon get rotated too and if I create a custom shape/image to use as the background the buttons clickable area is still a square. Any help would be appreciated?

[image: diamond button]

Comment: Check this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28898906/diamond-shaped-button-with-transparent-borders/28941079 . Also they recommend a library https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview

Comment: I tried that and didn't work but would like to learn how to implement it myself anway

Answer (score 1):

if you want change clickable area you have to intercept touch events and filter them. You need custom view for doing this

Comment: I cant find how to do that, guess i have some researching to do